# How do you set a trade rule on a station's subordinates?

Tags: x4-foundations

In the station individual instructions screen (or on a ship's individual orders) when I try to select a trade rule, the only option is "Off"

[image: Blacklists for Subordinates - Off only]

How do I use one of my trade rules?

[image: Global Orders - Trade Rules]

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you have to make a "Trade Restrictions" type blacklist in the blacklist section, instead of a trade rule.

[image]